# How to get "group or usernames" from folder security properties

Tags: c#

I have some problem. I tried to search solving in the internet, but didn't find them (they didn't work).

The problem is...

For example I have some folder: "directory1", I must get usernames and their permissions regarding this folder..

I found a screenshot (not my) to demonstrate what I mean:

[Link to the picture](http://s019.radikal.ru/i631/1205/1d/5e376f217de2.png)

How can I get these usernames etc? And is this hard to add new usernames with permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO question has an example with the types you need to use to get the information that you're looking for: [Duplicate GetAccessRules, FileSystemAccessRule entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507862/duplicate-getaccessrules-filesystemaccessrule-entries).

You can also modify permissions on the folder using the same underlying classes.