# Get permission level of a folder

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I have an EventHandler that checks permission level.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 1;
            XMLPermSheet.CreateXML();
            string directory = textBox1.Text;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
            DirectoryInfo[] sdi = di.GetDirectories();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo tdi in sdi)
            {
                if (!tdi.ToString().EndsWith("System Volume Information") && !tdi.ToString().Contains("$RECYCLE.BIN"))
                {
                    XMLPermSheet.AddPath(tdi.ToString(), id);
                    DirectorySecurity ds = tdi.GetAccessControl();

                    foreach (AccessRule rule in ds.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} || Identity = {1}; Access = {2} \r\n", tdi.ToString(),
                        rule.IdentityReference.Value, rule.AccessControlType));
                        XMLPermSheet.AddIdentity(rule.IdentityReference.Value.ToString(), rule.AccessControlType.ToString(), tdi.ToString());
                    }

                    id += 1;
                }
            }
    }
```

rule.AccessControlType.ToString() returns only "Allow" or "Deny" but I need to get something this:

View: True 
Add: True 
Modify: False 
Delete: False

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You mean its [`Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?..

Comment: Probably yes but this in meant for files and I need to get folder attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change **AccessRule** in your foreach to **FileSystemAccessRule**. Then you have access to the property FileSystemRights. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508604/3455216) explains how to get the rights.

Short version, on how to check if User or Group has Permission:

```
//Example: Change    
bool hasChangePermission = rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions);

//Example: Write
bool hasWritePermission = rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.Write);
```

Here's a small example method:

```
public string GetRuleAsString(FileSystemAccessRule rule)
{
    string userName = rule.IdentityReference.Value;

    //Example: Change    
    bool hasChangePermission = rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions);

    //Example: Write
    bool hasWritePermission = rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.Write);

    return String.Format("{0}\n Change: {1}\n Write: {2}", userName, hasChangePermission, hasWritePermission);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how to get AccessRights from a DirectoryInfo object?

Comment: So I did what you've told me to do and now I've this:

`var mask = (AccessRights)rule.AccessMask`

But i get errors that: The property or indexer 'System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRule.AccessMask' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible

Comment: Sorry thought it was a public property. I updated my answer again.

Comment: Edited my answer again and added an example of a help method.